# how to move end point of line in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

i'm in a problem and hope someone of u can help me. i'm working in a game in Android using **Andengine**. now i had a problem that take much time of me and i can't solve

i had a line drawn in the scene, i want to move the end point (x2, y2) to another point as animation within 1 or 2 sec.
for example, line **(x1 = 5, y1 = 0) and (x2 = 5, y2 = 10)** , i want this line be taller but in animation to be **(x1 = 5, y1 = 0) and (x2 = 5, y2 = 100)**

PLEASE help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution and it is very simple. I have created new Modifier that inherits from the `MoveModifier class` and override the method of update :

```
public class LineMoveModifier extends MoveModifier{

public LineMoveModifier(float pDuration, float pFromX, float pToX,
        float pFromY, float pToY) {
    super(pDuration, pFromX, pToX, pFromY, pToY);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public LineMoveModifier(final float pDuration, final float pFromX, final float pToX, final float pFromY, final float pToY, final IEntityModifierListener pEntityModifierListener, final IEaseFunction pEaseFunction) {
    super(pDuration, pFromX, pToX, pFromY, pToY, pEntityModifierListener, pEaseFunction);
}

@Override
protected void onSetValues(final IEntity pEntity, final float pPercentageDone, final float pX, final float pY) {
    Line x = (Line)pEntity;
    x.setPosition(x.getX1(), x.getY1(), pX, pY);
}
```

}

now when using it for example:

```
x = new Line(0, 0, 5, 5, 5, getVertexBufferObjectManager(), DrawType.DYNAMIC);
     LineMoveModifier lmm = new LineMoveModifier(5, 5, 400, 5, 700);
     mainScene.attachChild(x);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: +1 for solving it yourself and sharing ....also mark it as the correct answer pls..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Move Modifier](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/modifier/MoveModifier.java?r=ea4ff643a0e58857e92738a6e5449b6a362190cd)

```
MoveModifier modifier = new MoveModifier(1.5f, point.x, point.x, point.y, point.y + 30)
```

and than use registerEntityModifier to your point:

```
point.registerEntityModifier(modifier);
```

and in your updateHandler draw line:

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

    @Override
    public void reset() {}

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
           //draw line between 2 points
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Racoon for ur answer, but MoveModifier moves the whole line (it's position) not the end point of the line. i have found a solution and i will add it soon

Answer (score 0):

I think, it will be easier for you to detach the current line and create a new one with required elements. I think it will be faster and easier then using modifiers.

Comment: thanks SVS for ur answer, but i want an animation, not just drawing a line